# How to understand whether a Windows XP or 7 machine is switched on or off with PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, cmd

I want to get list which computers are online or offline on local network but I have to use PHP, HTML and JavaScript for this.

I used the `exec` command in PHP with "ping servername" but it makes too slow so I can get only 7 or 8 then PHP gives error computers situation but I need 50 computers situation.

I tried to reach a file from all computers like \lab4-01\c$ but it didn't work in PHP or JavaScript, but I failed again.

- How can I solve this question?

Comment: The actual verification is always going to be slow. You could e.g. set up a service that does the ping every minute then records the results in a DB, and your PHP code could read from that DB.

Comment: when i use db and fsockopen it is working great but i can use this function for 30 computers lab but also i set up a a service also it is working great then i will use first solution for little labs and i'm gonna use second solution for big labs in university, thanks for all answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ping is not a good idea since some networks filter ICMP traffic.
I'd use php functin fsockopen(); http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: You can also use nmap command wich returns the ip adresses of every active host on a given network
for example : nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 will return all active hosts ip adresses, you can cron this command and make your php script just parse it's output

Answer (score 1):

You should write a cron script which tests a few computers at a time, and updates a database table with the status and last updated time. The script will try to update first those computers who weren't updated in a long time. For instance for 10 computers at a time, your query will be ordered by updatetime and limited to 10, such as in `ORDER BY updatetime LIMIT 10`.

Your status page should not test the computers directly, but retrieve the data from DB, it  will be breezingly fast to show.

Be careful not to overlap executions of your cron script, or the machine runlevel could go up to the sky, for example if your cron executes every X minutes, you can set a lower maximum execution time